# How to draw a line on the baseline of the text in HTML/SVG/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to draw a line inside a span after some text. The line should extend the baseline of the text. E.g.:

Some text____________________ (this line, created with underlines, is too low)

My idea:

```
<span>Some text<svg><line x1=.. y1=.. x2=.. y2=.. /></svg></span>
```

But how do I have to set the svg-height an y-values of the line?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, using an SVG.

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
}

svg.baseline {
  width: 4em;
}

svg.baseline line {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 0.06;
}
```

```html
<span>
  Some text
  <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="baseline">
    <line x1="0" y1="0.97" x2="1" y2="0.97" />
  </svg>
</span>
```

The SVG, which is treated as an image, aligns with the baseline of the text by default.  All you need to do in the SVG is to draw a line at the very bottom of the SVG at your desired width.  You can set the length of the line by changing the width of the SVG in CSS.

This works at any font size.  Try changing the font size of the `<span>` in the CSS.  It's currently set to 30px.

Answer (score 3):

If it is for a single line , flex can easy help:

set *flex:1; to your svg and remove the pseudo rule*.

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}
span + span {
  font-size: 3em;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
<span>Some text</span>
```

or same as with the classic absolute pseudo :*(your svg becomes the pseudo )*

```css
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span + span {
  font-size: 3em;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  bottom: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
<span>Some text</span>
```

or in the flow with width and negative margin to reduce virtually width down to zero:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span + span {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: impact;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 1980px;
  margin-right:-1990px;
  border-bottom: 0.1em solid;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

```html
<span>Some text</span>
<span>Some text</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see, that margin-bottom or bottom is 0.25em. Is this value valid for any font?

Comment: @C.Hoffmann you may try a few fonts, but this should it for most of the fonts build correctly. Now, i have no idea for fancy or ding fonts. If you are unsure, you may use an inline-block container with a set width and equal negative margin and vertical-align:baseline. A third snippet added

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solutions above, here is another solution:

```css
.baseline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.baseline svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1pt;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1pt;
}
```

```html
<div class='baseline'>Hello my baseline
  <svg class='baseline'>
    <line x1='0' y1='50%' x2='100%' y2='50%' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

The height and the stroke-width should be the same value.